# rails : association tabel (has_and_belongs_to_many) not save any record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters, rails-models

i use rails 5 , simple form. in my app there is a Category model and there is a OnlineProduct model. i dont know why when i want to add some categories to my OnlineProduct association table remain empty and don't change.

Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord

  has_ancestry

  has_and_belongs_to_many :internet_products

end
```

InternetProduct model:

```
class InternetProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :business
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

InternetProduct controller:

```
  def new
     @internet_product = InternetProduct.new
  end
  def create
     @internet_product = InternetProduct.new(internet_product_params)

     respond_to do |format|
        if @internet_product.save
           format.html { redirect_to @internet_product, notice: 'Internet product was successfully created.' }
           format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @internet_product }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @internet_product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
     end
  end
private:
def internet_product_params
  params.require(:internet_product).permit(:name, :description, :mainpic, :terms_of_use,
                                       :real_price, :price_discount, :percent_discount,
                                       :start_date, :expire_date, :couponـlimitation, :slung,
                                       :title, :meta_data, :meta_keyword, :enability, :status,
                                       :like, :free_delivery, :garanty, :waranty, :money_back,
                                       :user_id, :business_id,
                                       categoriesـattributes: [:id, :title])
end
```

and in the view only the part of who relate to categories :

```
   <%= f.association :categories %>
```

all the categories list in view (form) but when i select some of them not save in database. in rails console i do this

```
 p = InternetProduct.find(5)
 p.categories = Category.find(1,2,3)
```

this save to database without any problem, what should i do ? 
tanks for reading this

Comment: you have and `OnlineProduct` join table?

Comment: yes inye. this is what i have:
    'class CategoriesInternetBons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
       def change
        create_table :categories_internet_products, id: false do |t|
          t.belongs_to :category, index: true
          t.belongs_to :internet_product, index: true
      
        end
       end 
    end'

Comment: edit your question and add this migration and better if you add your table schema of this three tables.

Comment: @inye , I think there is no problem in database schema because in rails console when i do this
b = internet_product.find(1)
b.categories = Category.find(2,3,4)
everything works fine.

Comment: more info more easy to help you

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to solve this. when we use has_and_belong_to_many or any other relation , if you want to use collection select in simple_form , in the model also should be add this command for nesting form

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
```

also in the controller in related method for example in the new we should

```
def new
  @internet_product = InternetProduct.new
  @internet_product.categories.build
end
```